# Trying to check if a column has "Attended" and then display the Else condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am trying make sure my program checks if a Text(Attended) is in a specific row and column and skip if it is.

But when i run it, the program still updates Attended and Date.

Code below..

```
 function doGet(request) {


   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(request.parameters.ssId).getActiveSheet();

   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

   var user = request.parameters.id;

   var status = request.parameters.status;

       for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {

         var check = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();

         if(check[i][0] != ATTENDED){

          if (data[i][0] == user[0]){

           sheet.getRange(i+1, 3,1,1).setValue(status[0]);

           var date = new Date();

           sheet.getRange(i+1, 2,1,1).setValue(date);
  
           var result = "Welcome "+ user + ".";

           return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);

          }

         }

         else{var resulted = "You have already registered! Thank you.";

         return ContentService.createTextOutput(resulted);}

        }

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your condition is  `if(check[i][0] != ATTENDED)`
- You do not have a variable called `ATTENDED`
- If you want to compare the sheet data against the STRING `ATTENDED`, then you have to define the string as such - `"ATTENDED"` (mind case sensitivity)
- Also, if you define `var check = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();` you assign to `check` a single value rather than a 2D value range (opposed to `getValues()`)
- Thus, `check[i][0]` does not exist
- Also, I do not know what `request` looks like, but you need to doublecheck iehter it is an array through which you can loop